# Reshape numpy array having only one dimension

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

In order to get a numpy array from a `list` I make the following:

```
np.array([i for i in range(0, 12)])
```

And get:

```
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

Then I would like to make a **(4,3)** matrix from this array:

```
np.array([i for i in range(0, 12)]).reshape(4, 3)
```

and I get the following matrix:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

But if I know that I will have **3 * n** elements in the initial `list` how can I reshape my numpy array, because the following code

```
np.array([i for i in range(0,12)]).reshape(a.shape[0]/3,3)
```

Results in the error

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: `int(a.shape[0]/3)` should do

Comment: a.reshape(-1, 3) is more general

Comment: @nsaura indeed, you are right

Comment: @Dav2357. `a.shape[0] // 3` is more elegant if you insist on going down that road.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, `np.array([i for i in range(0, 12)])` is a less elegant way of saying `np.arange(12)`.

Secondly, you can pass `-1` to one dimension of reshape (both the function [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) and the method [`np.ndarray.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape)). In your case, if you know the total size is a multiple of 3, do

```
np.arange(12).reshape(-1, 3)
```

to get a 4x3 array. From the docs:

> One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

As a side note, the reason that you get the error is that regular division, even for integers, automatically results in a `float` in Python 3: `type(12 / 3)` is `float`. You can make your original code work by doing `a.shape[0] // 3` to use integer division instead. That being said, using `-1` is much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-1` in `.reshape`. If you specify one dimension, Numpy will determine the other dimension automatically when possible[1].

```
np.array([i for i in range(0,12)]).reshape(-1, 3)
```

[1] https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: Better to use `arange` then a list comprehension when using `numpy` here