# How to resize a one dimensional array to a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have the following array

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

and I want to reshape it such that the output is

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3],
               [4,5,6],
               [7,8,9]])
```

Is there a way to do this, without using any loops?

Comment: arr.reshape(-1,3)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshape numpy array having only one dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744554/reshape-numpy-array-having-only-one-dimension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the array.

```
B = np.reshape(A, (-1, 3))
```

where `-1` infers the size of the new dimension from the size of the input array.

Answer (score 1):

use [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) in numpy

```
np.reshape(arr,(3,3))
```

output

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```